# Input within if statement python3

Tags: python-3.x

This program works fine in python2, but prints error after inputing '1' at the prompt when running it in python3. I'm wondering if there is still a way to accept user input within an if statement or if I'd have to go about this differently. My program below:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
select_one = input('Please enter a number from the menu below: 
\n1.Convert Celcius to Farenheit \n2. Convert Farenheit to Celcius\n>\t')

if select_one == 1:
  c = input('Please enter the temperature\n>\t')
  f = c*(9.0/5.0)+32
  print(f, 'F', sep='')
elif select_one == 2:
  f = input('Please enter the temperature\n>\t')
  c = f*(5.0/9.0)-32
  print(c, 'C', sep='')
else:
  print('Error')
```

Comment: "prints error" - *what error?*

Comment: From the codeblock, else: print('error'). When I run the program, I input the number "1", which is assigned to variable "select_one". In python2, this prompts me with "Please enter the temperature >". In python3, the program will only run successfully with print statements. I'd like to know if it's possible to ask a question, wait for input, then display another question based on the input that would require a second input from the user.

Comment: OK, so in Python 3, what is the value of "select_one"?  Print it and see.

Comment: It prints 1, after inputting a 1 at the prompt. So it's storing the value from the first prompt correctly. I don't understand why the if statement doesn't validate it as a 1, though.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are accidentally relying on the fact that in Python 2, `input()` would parse the input, not just return it as a string.  So "1" (str) becomes 1 (int).  But in Python 3, `input()` does what `raw_input()` used to do, so the returned value is always a string.

To fix it, change this:

```
if select_one == 1:
```

To this:

```
if select_one == "1":
```

Answer (score 0):

By default the `input()` takes value as string in python 3.. so you might want to change input as

```
select_one =int( input('Please enter a number from the menu below: \n1.Convert Celcius to Farenheit \n2. Convert Farenheit to Celcius\n>\t'))
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers will get you partway, but a nicer way to handle input in your script would be something like this:

```
def input_type(prompt, outputType):
    while TrueL
        try:
            return outputType(input(prompt))
        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid input. Required type is {}".format(outputType.__name__))
```

You can then replace your first call to `input` with `input_type(<your prompt>, int)` and the second two with `input_type(<your prompt>, float)` without changing the rest of your code.

As a side note - your conversion from fahrenheit to celsius isn't quite right. You might want to test it by converting from celsius to fahrenheit and back again.